# Is there an alternative to Original Molex Crimp hand Tools?

Tags: connector, pcb-assembly, tools, crimp

I have used molex products before and i have been happy with them . Recently they introduced a new series called molex [Nano-Fit](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=nanofit_power_connectors&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction&utm_source=dpb&utm_medium=lit&utm_campaign=general) , very interesting product until i saw there crimping tool marketing strategy :

2 separate tools for different wire diameter and it cost around 400$ each.

1. [for 24 to 26 AWG](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0638276000_APPLICATION_TOOLIN.xml)
2. [for 20 to 22 AWG](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0638275600_APPLICATION_TOOLIN.xml)

so i have to invest 800$ before even buying or using or testing a single connector which is a lot for me ( i donot have a mass production line and i sell in 10s to 100s of pieces)

Question : is there a way to get the crimping tools at much lower prices than digikey or mouser ?? is there a walk-around to crimping like soldering or using a universal crimper or piler ? is there Chinese copies for these tools for cheaper prices ?

any solution or idea is appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: The crimp doesn't look terribly different from JST XH. Maybe you can use a universal tool such as the Engineer PA-09.

Comment: You have my sympathy - it looks like MOLEX are pulling people's pants down on this.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams , thanks because of you i found this article : http://tech.mattmillman.com/info/crimpconnectors/   . although it doesnot give a complete satisfaction , i does answer some of my concerns , such as soldering

Comment: For some of the widely adopted connector families Molex makes lower cost crimp tools, which they call "service grade tools".  Here's one such [example](http://www.alliedelec.com/molex-incorporated-64016-0201/70091298/).

Comment: @NickAlexeev , clearly this is not the case with these connectors , since they are still new , and they intentionally made 2 different crimpers . However i will check